# Diferença entre os métodos de ordenação selection dort, insertion sort e bubble sort

Tags: classificação, estrutura-de-dados

Estou estudando a disciplina **estrutura de dados** e estou desenvolvendo programas em C++.

Conheço basicamente estes três tipos de ordenação (*selection sort*, *insertion sort* e *bubble sort*), mas não sei detalhadamente a diferença entre os três tipos.

Quais são estas diferenças e em que casos utilizar cada tipo de ordenação?

Se também for possível, gostaria de um exemplo de cada tipo de ordenação.

Answer (score 5):

- **Selection Sort**: A cada iteração, procura em toda a parcela não ordenada do vetor pelo menor (ou maior) elemento e o coloca na posição correta.   Assim, na i-ésima iteração, o i-ésimo menor elemento vai para a posição `i`, e assim por diante.
- **Insertion Sort**: Itera-se crescentemente entre as posições. Para cada posição, pega seu elemento e regride-o no vetor até encaixá-lo na posição correta (quando encontrar o primeiro elemento menor que ele).
- **Bubble sort**: Pega dois elementos adjacentes e troca-os de posição se, e somente se, estiverem fora de ordem. Faz isso com todos pares de elementos a cada iteração. Ao final da mesma, o menor (ou maior) elemento ainda não ordenado estará na posição correta. Repete-se isso até o final.

Você pode vê-los funcionando visualmente [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg).

Todos esses são algoritmos elementares e fáceis de implementar. Tanto o *Bubble* quanto o *Selection* possuem complexidade **O(n²)** em todos os casos. O *Insertion*, por outro lado, roda em **O(n)** no melhor caso (como por exemplo, se o vetor já estiver em ordem crescente). Assim, ele acaba sendo um algoritmo melhor para propósitos gerais.