# Qual é esse método de ordenação?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, classificação, bubblesort

Estava estudando estrutura de dados por vídeos de um projeto para ingressar em uma empresa, e em uma aula específica o professor fez um código em VisuAlg falando que era o método de ordenação bolha, mas o bubble sort baseia-se na ideia de comparar repetidamente pares de elementos adjacentes e, em seguida, trocar as suas posições se estiverem na ordem errada, o que não é esse caso.

O susposto bubble sort:

```
var
numeros : vetor[1..5] de inteiro
i, j, aux : inteiro

inicio

para i de 1 ate 5 faca
    escreval ("Numeros", i)
    leia (numeros[i])
fimpara

para i de 1 ate 5 faca
    para j de 1 ate 5 faca
        se numeros [j] > numeros[i] entao
            aux <- numeros[i]
            numeros[i] <- numeros[j]
            numeros[j] <- aux
        fimse
    fimpara
fimpara

fimalgoritmo
```

O bubble sort verdadeiro, somente a parte da ordenação ("troca" foi declarada como variável lógica/booleana):

```
troca <- verdadeiro

enquanto troca= verdadeiro faca
         troca <- falso
         para i de 1 ate 4 faca
               se numeros[i] > numeros[i+1] entao
                    aux <- numeros[i]
                        numeros[i] <- numeros[i+1]
                     numeros[i+1] <- aux
                     troca <- verdadeiro
               fimse
         fimpara
fimenquanto
```

Gostaria de saber qual o nome do método de ordenação do "suposto bubble sort" para ler mais sobre o assunto e saber em quais projetos ele poderia ser utilizado, sabendo os prós e contras já difundidos.

Comment: Mas o bubblesort compara pares de elementos adjacentes, e esse não. Ele troca pares distantes. Estou correto?

Comment: Irei fazer agora mesmo e vou editar.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda, talvez já responda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165069/

Comment: Isso ai explica bem os três métodos, e está correto. Mas não especifica que método é esse do "suposto bubble sort", talvez seja um método tão ruim que não está na literatura? Mas por ser um método tão simples e de código fácil para ser desenvolvido, acredito que deva existir algo sobre.

Comment: Se for seguir a descrição de lá acredito que seja o selection, mas ainda cabe aquela otimização que falei, não tem pq iniciar o loop interno `j` do `1`, e sim do `i` (as posições anteriores ao `i` já estariam corretas).

Comment: Só tem um problema, esse código ele realmente procura pelo maior valor, mas não coloca na posição correta, e nem procura pela parcela não ordenada, pq ele só terminar de ordenar no final.
O método dele organizar em linhas:
54321
45321
34521
23451
12345

Comment: em "teoria" devia ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/t4Xm8C - adaptei pra indice zero só por ter trocado a linguagem (e fiz a otimização do loop), mas o resto é o mesmo (trocar posição se > ou <, conforme a ordem desejada). Tambem não precisou de aux pq o list ( ) do PHP abstrai isso. (só testei de curioso mesmo, pra ver se tinha passado batido algum detalhe). Bom, em alguém respondendo, tambem espero algo mais elaborado :D

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Bacco, terminei de encontrar, ele se chama Exchange Sort, segue link da explicação: https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Exchange.htm.

Comment: Você pode postar uma resposta para sua própria pergunta se quiser, sempre naquela idéia de elaborar pensando em referência para um público amplo (por exemplo, pondo o algoritmo, explicando o que caracteriza ele, pode até usar o link como complemento e devidos créditos, mas é fundamental que a resposta não dependa dele)

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei a resposta, o método de ordenação se chama Exchange Sort, é semelhante ao Bubble Sort, pois compara elementos do array e troca aqueles que estão fora de ordem. O Exchange Sort compara o primeiro elemento com cada elemento seguinte da matriz, fazendo as trocas necessárias. Quando a primeira passagem pela matriz é concluída, a classificação de troca pega o segundo elemento e o compara com cada elemento seguinte da matriz e realiza as trocas do que estão fora de ordem. Esse processo de classificação continua até que todo o array seja ordenado.

Referência: [mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Exchange.htm](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Exchange.htm)